# Design the circuit such that the output voltage is 2.4V

Tags: diodes

[image]

How would  I figure out the value of R? How would I analyse this circuit?

Comment: Is this a homework excercise? Have you learned the Shockley diode model?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. In terms of diodes the furthest we went was zener diodes

Comment: The real answer is get rid of the three diodes and use a [TLV431](http://www.ti.com/product/tlv431).

Comment: the answer will change with change in temperature i.e. if T=20K ur answer would be 139 ohms and if ur T=25K ur answer would be 159 ohms,so its better to get to know about the temperature also.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework should have an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is a horrible way to design a circuit to have a fixed output voltage. You would never do this in the real world. But I'll assume it's a homework problem and it's meant to test your knowledge of diode behavior.

The key is to remember the Shockley diode equation

$$I = I_s\ \exp(\frac{qV}{nRT}-1)$$

You know one point on the characteristic curve (V=0.7 V when I=1 mA), but there are two unknown parameters to describe the diode: \$I_s\$ and \$n\$. You'll have to assume you know one of them close enough and then use the equation to get the other one. *n* is more likely to be close to a "typical" value, so I'd choose \$n=1\$ (If you've been given SPICE models for any "typical" diodes in class, then use the *n* values from one of those models instead of just n=1) and then find \$I_s\$ to match the given datapoint.

Once you have \$I_s\$ then you have to find the \$I\$ that gives you 0.8 V per diode in order to get 2.4 V at the output.

But again, you'd never design a circuit this way in reality. If the load on the output draws more than microamps it's going to change the output voltage by more than you want (given that the person who designed the problem seems to care about the difference between 2.1 and 2.4 V output)

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean, it's a lot of work trying to figure out the values. You have to go through a lot.

Comment: You'll also find that it takes quite a bit of current to get to 0.8 V --- which means this circuit is wasting way more power than it should have to.

Comment: Honestly I think there is a typo in the problem and it should say the goal is an output of 2.1 V. Then you just have to figure out the resistor value to get 1 mA.

Comment: The answer somewhat follows. It says the R is 139 ohms